# How to get last 5 docs in sequential order?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Say I have **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10** in database (based on `timestamp` order).

I want to get **6, 7, 8, 9, 10** in sequential order.

```
  MessageModel
    .find()
    .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
    .limit(5)
    .exec()
    .then(messages => console.log(messages))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The above method will give me **10, 9, 8, 7, 6**.

I tried to sort twice:

```
  MessageModel
    .find()
    .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
    .limit(5)
    .sort({ timestamp: 1 })
    .exec()
    .then(messages => console.log(messages))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But this will give me **1, 2, 3, 4, 5**.

Does Mongoose have a way to get last 5 docs in sequential order?

Comment: The referenced question does not appear to be a duplicate, as it doesn't have the requirement that the results are sorted.   And as you've pointed out, the answer doesn't provide a way to do it in mongo/mongoose.  You should be able to do `MessageModel.aggregate([
 {
  $sort: {timestamp: -1}
 },
 {
  $limit: 5
 },
 {
  $sort: {timestamp: 1}
 }
])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement you can use aggregate query

```
MessageModel.aggregate([
   { $sort : { timestamp: -1} },
   { $limit : 5 },
   { $sort : { timestamp: 1} }
])
.exec();
```

Comment: Actually I did not see that comment when I was answering. However may answer matched with @Wake comment so if you want I can delete my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to efficiently reverse the order of the elements in your `messages` array in place to put them back in ascending order:

```
MessageModel
    .find()
    .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
    .limit(5)
    .exec()
    .then(messages => {
        messages.reverse();
        console.log(messages);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```